# OpenShift origins - default created routes not working

Tags: dns, openshift, kubernetes, openshift-origin

**Version**

- OpenShift Master: v1.5.0-rc.0+49a4a7a Kubernetes
- Master:v1.5.2+43a9be4

**Problem description**

I have installed OpenShift using OpenShift-Ansible, and I have set it to include Metrics.

The metrics URL is hawkular-metrics.apps.console.mydomain.com - but this, and all other automatically created urls do not work.

However, if I create a route, for example metrics.console.mydomain.com, it does work.

My domain name settings are:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the DNS resolution. Everything related to *.apps.console.mydomain.com should be resolved with the IP of the master (in case you are running a single master installation) as seems to be done for *.console.mydomain.com